# Stacking blocks on the right or above

Tags: combinatorics

Imaging if I have n sequares where the first one is fixed at the origin. The subsequent blocks may be stacked either on the right on top of the previous block. If one configuration can **rotate** into another, they are counted as the same configuration. If one can just be mirrored into another, but not rotated, then they are counted as two configs.

E.g.
O = start, R = right, U = up

OURR and ORRU is the same, but OUUR and ORRU are different.

How many different chains can n blocks form?

I was thinking, if there are n blocks there are $2^{n-1}$ chains in total. Each chain
rotating 180 degrees gives a repetition so I need to divide by 2 giving $2^{n-2}$ distinct chains.

However, this is incorrect. Imaging 4 blocks, the configurations are ORRR, ORRU, ORUR, OURU, OUUR, which gives 5, so that breaks my relation immediately. How should I do the counting here?

Comment: I think you have the right idea, but you're undercounting (by a factor of 2) the configurations that are unchanged by a 180 degree rotation. I'd try counting those separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK following Karl's hint, I think I came to the solution:

If $n = 1$, $N = 1$ trivially.

If $n\geq 2$, the total number of ways should be
$$
N = \frac{1}{2}(2^{n-1} + 2^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}) - 1
$$
The $2^{n-1}$ counts all chains. $2^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ double counts all chains unchanged after 180 degree rotation, divided by 2 to remove the degeneracy due to rotate by 180 degree. In that case, we are not over removing chains. Minus 1 in the end for the double counting due to the streight chain (i.e. all right and all up are the same configuration).

In the end, we can put the two cases together as
$$
N = \frac{1}{2}(2^{n-1} + 2^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}) - \textrm{sgn}(n-1)
$$
where sgn$(n-1)$ is the sign of $(n-1)$.